# jQuery display image issue 

Tags: jquery

I have PHP page where users can upload photos (using Ajax & PHP script). Those uploaded photos (thumbs) are shown after upload in DIV below upload field.

Then, after hitting send button I want to clone that DIV at that same page at message board, bellow other messages with or without uploaded photos.

When I try to do that with:

```
var pht = $("#photos").clone().addClass('p_pht');
```

and try to display sent photos bellow sent message like this:

```
$("div#wall").append('<div class=msg>'+ message +'</div><div class=n_pht>'+ pht +'</div>');
```

I get jQuery error message "[object Object]" in place where the photos should be displaying.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

`pht.html()` instead of `pht`.

```
$("div#wall").append('<div class=msg>'+ message +'</div><div class=n_pht>'+ pht.html() +'</div>');
```

If `message` is also a jQuery object then give `message.html()`.

Comment: Thanks. But now I have a problem with jquery plugin "fancybox" (for displaying images). It does not work if I try to call it like:

var pht = $("#photos").clone().fancybox();

What is the problem with this plugin?